# Python: 2 Conditions - Read in characters Until x, and Count Vowels

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

Specification: Read in characters until the user enters a full stop '.'. Show the number of lowercase vowels.

So far, I've succeeded in completing the read loop and printing out 'Vowel Count: '. However, vowel count always comes to 0.
I've just started. I'm struggling with placement for 'Show the number of lowercase vowels'
Should I define vowels = ... at the top? Or put it in a loop later? Do I create a new loop? I haven't been able to make it work.
Thanks

```
c = str(input('Character: '))
count = 0

while c != '.':
        count += 1
        c = str(input('Character: '))

print("Vowel count =", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem. You should add 2 conditions in your code. You check If the character is vowel and if is lowercase:

```
c = str(input('Character: '))
count = 0

while c != '.':
        if c in 'aeyio' and c.islower():
            count += 1
        c = str(input('Character: '))

print("Vowel count =", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase Vowels correspond to a set of numbers in the ascii table, same case applies to the '.'

```
c = str(input('Character: '))
count = 0
lowerCaseVowel = [97, 101, 105, 111, 117]

for _ in c:
    # check for .
    if ord(_) == 46:
        break
    if ord(_) in lowerCaseVowel:
        count += 1

print("Vowel count = ", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

- In `while` Loop you can add `if` condition to check if letter is in lower case using string method `islower()` and is letter is vowel.  if both condition satisfy then increase count by 1.
- You don't have to convert input string into `str` type since input string is always in string type.
- Also, outside while loop you can declare variable as empty string.

---

```
c =''
count = 0

while c != '.':
        c = input('Character: ')
        if c.islower() and c in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
            count += 1

print("Vowel count =", count)
```